# Get behavior related configuration from code

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Are behavior related configurations accessible? In this specific case, a behavior was attached to a table. I would like to know if it's possible to get the fields property in some way, later on in code?

```
<?php
class MyRandomTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        ...
        // Add Cipher behavior
        $this->addBehavior('CipherBehavior.Cipher', [
                'fields' => [
                        'original' => 'string',
                        'changed' => 'string',
                ]
        ]);
    }
    ...
}
?>
```

If I load the table and dump the content, I do not see the behavior listed:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('MyRandomTable');
var_dump($table);
```

Partial dump content:

```
protected '_behaviors' => 
    object(Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry)[170]
      protected '_table' => 
        &object(Cake\ORM\Table)[172]
      protected '_methodMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_finderMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_loaded' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_eventManager' => 
        object(Cake\Event\EventManager)[165]
          protected '_listeners' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected '_isGlobal' => boolean false
          protected '_eventList' => null
          protected '_trackEvents' => boolean false
      protected '_eventClass' => string '\Cake\Event\Event' (length=17)
```

What I'd like to do, in a controller, is to get the fields and pass those on to a view.

**Edit #1**

Using CakePHP v3.3.16

**Edit #2**

I'm seeing behavior information as I had missed the plugin prefix when loading the table:

```
$table = TableRegistry::get('PluginName.MyRandomTable');
```

Shows:

```
protected '_behaviors' => 
    object(Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry)[143]
      protected '_table' => 
        &object(PluginName\Model\Table\MyRandomTable)[94]
      protected '_methodMap' => 
        array (size=4)
          'timestamp' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'touch' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'encrypt' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'decrypt' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      protected '_finderMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_loaded' => 
        array (size=2)
          'Timestamp' => 
            object(Cake\ORM\Behavior\TimestampBehavior)[181]
              ...
          'Cipher' => 
            object(CipherBehavior\Model\Behavior\CipherBehavior)[192]
              ...
      protected '_eventManager' => 
        object(Cake\Event\EventManager)[175]
          protected '_listeners' => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
          protected '_isGlobal' => boolean false
          protected '_eventList' => null
          protected '_trackEvents' => boolean false
      protected '_eventClass' => string '\Cake\Event\Event' (length=17)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your table class file is incorrect, it needs a namespace, otherwise it cannot be found, and you'll end up with an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` (a so called auto/generic-table) instead of concrete subclass thereof, hence your behavior is missing.

That being said, it depends on how the behavior has been programmed. If it follows the default configuration pattern, then you can access the configuration via its `config()` or `getConfig()` (as of CakePHP 3.4) methods.

Of course you have to access the behavior, not just the table class to which it is attached. This is done using the behavior registry, which is available via the `Table::behaviors()` method:

```
$fields = $table->behaviors()->get('Cipher')->config('fields');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Accessing Loaded Behaviors](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#accessing-loaded-behaviors)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Re-configuring Loaded Behaviors](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#re-configuring-loaded-behaviors)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\BehaviorRegistry](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.BehaviorRegistry.html)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Behavior](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Configuration > Disabling Generic Tables](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#disabling-generic-tables)**

Comment: My table has a namespace, I just omitted it to keep relevant parts I thought.

Comment: You were partially there... since I'm loading a plugin table, I needed to prefix it with the plugin name. I now see some behavior metadata/info.

Comment: This works... had a typo in your command, it's "behavior" not "behaviour" :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, fixed the brit-po :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get Column names of a table by `schema()->columns()`.

**Example -**

```
$getColumnArray = $this->Users->schema()->columns();//return Users Table Colums Name Array
$getColumnArray = $this->Users->associations()->keys()//return Users assocation table key
```